# Compute$\sum\limits_s\frac{s^{n+1}}{s-1}$ where the sum enumerates the $k$th roots $s$ of $2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

> I am trying to prove that
>   $$\sum_{r=0}^{k-1} \frac{(2^{1/k}w^r)^{n+1}}{2^{1/k}w^r-1}=2^{\lfloor n/k\rfloor +1} k$$
>   for integer $n\geq 0$, where $w$ is the primitive $k^{th}$ root of unity (meaning that $2^{1/k}w^r$ for $r=0,\dots,k-1$ are the $k^{th}$ roots of two) and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ (the floor function) gives the integer part of $x$.

Having tried this out numerically I'm confident this is the answer, but finding it hard to prove.

I have tried writing $w=\cos(2 \pi /k)+i\sin(2\pi /k)$, but things get messy quickly.

I've also tried re-writing as

$$\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}(2^{1/k}w^r)^{n} + \frac{(2^{1/k}w^r)^{n}}{2^{1/k}w^r-1}$$

but although the first term is simple enough to analyze I have the same sorts of problems with the second as I had originally due to the roots on the bottom.

Any ideas would be gratefully received.

Comment: Note that each term in the sum is $$\frac{(2^{1/k}w^r)^{n+1}}{2^{1/k}w^r-1}=\frac{(2^{1/k}w^r)^{n}}{1-2^{-1/k}w^{-r}}=\sum_{j=-\infty}^n2^{j/k}w^{rj}$$ and that $$\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}w^{rj}=k\mathbf 1_{k\mid j}$$ hence, exchanging the sums over $r$ and $j$,  the sum to be evaluated is $$\sum_{j=-\infty}^n2^{j/k}k\mathbf 1_{k\mid j}=k\sum_{\ell:\ell\leqslant n/k}2^\ell$$ using the change of variable $j=k\ell$. Evaluating the last sum, using the fact that, for every integer $L$, $$\sum_{\ell=-\infty}^L2^\ell=2^{L+1}$$ yields the result.

Comment: More generally, considering the elementary $k$th root $b=a^{1/k}e^{2i\pi/k}$ of some real number $a>1$, $$\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}\frac{(b^r)^{n+1}}{b^r-1}=k\,\frac{a^{\lfloor n/k\rfloor+1}}{a-1}$$

Comment: @Did thank you very much. That i exactly what I was looking for. I don't think I would have seen the geometric progression has I stared at it for a long time. That was the key step I was missing. Do you want to make this into an answer and I will accept?

Comment: Thanks also to whoever rephrased the question. Wasn't sure about how specifi/general to be. Seems like more specific is better.

Comment: You are welcome (twice). Why not expand my comment into a full answer that you would post yourself and even, after a while and if the community seems to consider it is correct, accept it?

Answer (score 1):

First cosider the summand:

$$\frac{(2^{1/k}w^r)^{n+1}}{2^{1/k}w^r-1}$$
which can be re-written as 
$$\frac{(2^{1/k}w^r)^{n}}{1-2^{-1/k}w^{-r}}$$
which we can further recognise as the solution to a geometric sum:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(2^{1/k}w^r)^{n}(2^{-1/k}w^{-r})^{j}\\
=\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(2^{1/k}w^r)^{n-j},\\
=\displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^{0}(2^{1/k}w^r)^{n+j},\\
=\displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^{n}(2^{1/k}w^r)^{j}.$$
Hence 
$$\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}\frac{(2^{1/k}w^r)^{n+1}}{2^{1/k}w^r-1}=\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}\displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^{n}(2^{1/k}w^r)^{j},\\
=\displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^{n}2^{j/k}\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}w^{rj},\\
=\displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^{n}2^{j/k}k\mathbb{I}_{k|j},$$
where $\mathbb{I}_{k|j}$ is unity if  $\quad j\mod k=0$ and zero otherwise.
In the penultimate line we have used
$$\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}w^{rj}=k\mathbb{I}_{k|j},$$ a propert of the $k^{th}$ roots of unity.

Letting $j=kl$ for integer $l\leq n/k$ gives
$$\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}\frac{(2^{1/k}w^r)^{n+1}}{2^{1/k}w^r-1}=\sum_{l=0}^{\lfloor n/k \rfloor} 2^l=2^{\lfloor n/k \rfloor+1}k.$$